# How Docker uses Python?

Tags: docker

I am running a *dockerised* jupyter notebook on a Centos server. One of the jupyter's task takes a lot of resources to complete and I noticed that my server runs slowly at that moment.

This is how I run my container, notice the `shm-size` argument (used by jupyter while doing parallel jobs):

```
docker run -t --shm-size=512m -v /opt/notebooks:/opt/notebooks -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3:ml-ready /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

What I don't understand is that I can see several `python`interpreter instances when through the `top` command. But none through `pgrep -af python`. When I stop my container, CPU's load comes back to normal and there's no `python` processes in the `top` command. So it looks like Docker processes are visible on the host, as far as I know it is impossible, so what is happening ?

Comment: `pgrep -af` searches through the command lines of the processes, which doesn't include `python` in your case. `top` shows the executed binary, which happens to be python. Try pressing `c` in top to show command lines instead.

Comment: I guess I am just surprised that commands launched within docker appears on the host. I should reformat my post or do another one. Thanks anyway for the useful `c` trick, really neat.

Comment: It's normal for the host to see containerised processes.  The containers themselves are limited in what they can do or see, not the host.   BTW, finding python processes with `ps` can sometimes be problematic because the python community believes that running python scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` is a good idea.  This mangles ARGV[0], which makes it difficult to find specific named scripts with `ps` alone.